# How do we say “The house must have already been bought! We should have come earlier.” in German?

Tags: grammar, modal-verb, passive

In English, we often use the ‘*must + have* + p.p’ to draw a conclusion about a particular situation we are witnessing. For instance, arriving at the gate of an house which has been on sale for a while, I tell my wife, after seeing some trucks being unloaded and words of felicitations being exchanged between some people: “O love! We are late! The house must have already been bought/sold.” The must-pattern is used when there is high probability for the veracity of the speaker’s conclusion. Should we be less certain about the circumstances, we tend to dilute the certainty by using ‘*might + have* + p.p.’

Here is a summary of what I have learnt about the passive form in German, yet none seems to fit the example I have given above.

- **Present:** „Das Haus wird gekauft.“ corresponding to “The house is being bought.”
  It must be noted that using *werden*+p.p emphasises the action rather than the result, i.e. to say “the house is bought” we should either say „Das Haus ist gekauft.“ or use the perfect form below.
- **Perfect:** „Das Haus ist gekauft worden.“ corresponding to “The house has been bought.”
  I have also come to realise that this pattern is used when the speaker intends to break something new to his hearer the same way as in English.
- **Past:** „Das Haus <del>war</del> wurde gekauft.“ corresponding to “The house was bought.”
- **Past Perfect:** „Das Haus war gekauft worden.“ corresponding to “The house had been bought.”
- **Future:** „Das Haus wird gekauft werden.“ corresponding to “The house will be bought.”
- **Future Perfect:** „Das Haus wird gekauft <del>werden</del> worden sein.“ corresponding to “The house will have been bought.”
  This usage requires modification by time-adverbs of some sort: „Bis Freitag wird das Haus gekauft werden sein.“ “The house will have been bought by Friday.”

The last form in particular is interesting in as much as it differs, at least in the English form, from ‘*must+have*+p.p’ structure in only one element, i.e. *will* vs. *must*.
So, considering all this, can we possibly translate the sentence in the question as follows?

„**Das Haus muss bereits gekauft worden sein.** Wir hätten früher kommen sollen.“

Comment: Although _gekauft_ ‘bought’ isn’t wrong, _verkauft_ ‘sold’ would be more idiomatic to use here in German. To express less certainty you could use _scheint_ or _wird [wohl]_ instead of _muss_, but then you’ll need to add _zu_ before _sein_, possibly replacing _worden_, which some people tend to hyper-correct to _geworden_.

Comment: There is no difference between English and German grammar in this respect: The correct form in English is a past progressive passive with additional auxilliary *must*. German does not have a progressive form, so it is simply past passive with an auxiliary *müssen*. Because there is an auxilliary, the past tense must be perfect, cannot be preterite.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is perfectly fine, although as Crissov notes, "verkauft" would be more idiomatic than "gekauft". Just be aware that the German construction can have two different, only tangentially related, meanings:

1. High-probability supposition:

> "Das Haus muß schon verkauft worden sein" = "I suppose it must have
>   been sold already."

2. Rule-based precondition:

> "Damit die Hypothek gewährt werden kann, muß das Haus bereits verkauft
>   worden sein." = "A mortgage can only be approved if the house has
>   already been sold."

Comment: To add to this - I think this is one of the typical cases, where modal particles are used in German. Adding "wohl" ("Das Haus muss wohl schon verkauft worden sein") will state a bit less certainty, but I think it is a bit more idiomatic, at least in spoken German. And after all, one is not sure, otherwise one would have said "Das Haus ist schon verkauft worden". You could also say "Das Haus ist wohl schon verkauft worden", which is less complex, and roughly on the same uncertainty scale as your English suggestion.

Comment: @Gerhard That's true, "wohl" is often used to disambiguate in favor of (1), and in fact it's so decisive that it can do the job alone, without usung "muß" at all.

Comment: With “Zustandspassiv” instead of “Vorgangspassiv” your suggestion would become _das Haus ist wohl schon verkauft _ without the _worden_.